# How to create an unordered_map in shared memory without boost?

Tags: c++, ipc

I have a `unordered_map` container, which i need to share it for two process(one writes, one read).

I known it's not simple, because map container is not a continueous memory container, share pointer don't work.

I have searched the solution for a while, I know `boost` may helps, but for some reason, i can't use boost.

I think this is a widely-needed requirements, Is there any new good method can be used to achieve this?

Comment: you can write a custom allocator. Or consider to use a `std::vector<std::pair<key,value>>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai thanks, i will try, for custom allocator, i am reading about std::pmr

Comment: An alternative may be to put the two threads that need access to the `unordered_map` inside the same process. If that is a possible refactoring, you'll be able to solve the synchronization with pure standard C++ mechanisms.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, multi-thread will be easy. but currently, multi-process is what i must use

Comment: And your map better be implemented without any pointers. Because it is not guaranteed that different processes will map the same shared memory segment at the same virtual address. It's possible to do so, but that's not guaranteed. And unless the shared memory segment is mapped at the same virtual address, all pointers are now worthless.

Comment: As soon as you cross process boundaries, C++ can't really help because you leave the boundaries of the language.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't support IPC, you will have to use third-party libraries or OS specific APIs. You might want to look at ZeroMQ, Google it

Comment: look at pmr namespace in std. use unordered_map from that and monotonic_buffer_resource. create shared mem via usual way shm_open/mmap and contruct monotonic_buffer_resource over this memory block